# Get the wiki title in my Redmine wiki page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

How can I get the wiki title in my Redmine wiki page?

I get the name of the project with `context[:project].identifier`, and I tried `context[:wiki]` but it doesn't work ...

I'm using Redmine 1.4.4, and here my code:

```
EDIT: # my_plugin/lib/hooks.rb

class MkdocHookListener < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  def view_layouts_base_content(context={})
    @content =  ""
    if context[:controller].is_a?(WikiController)
      @content << "<br/>projet ="
      @content << context[:project].identifier
    end
    return content_tag("p align='right'", @content)
  end
end

# myplugin/init.rb:

require 'redmine'
require_dependency 'hooks'

Redmine::Plugin.register :my_plugin do
  ...
end
```

Thanks !

EDIT: I just want to get the wiki title on the wiki-page, then I can use my home-made plugin.

Comment: This is [list of hooks](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Hooks_List) and `view_layouts_base_content` does not have content at all. Why you try to patch Redmine using this hook? I think it is general hook which is called on ALL pages (or almost all pages). What wiki title would you like  to find on non-wiki pages? I can't find any hook on wiki pages. Maybe try alternative way to patch. I used gem `deface` when couldn't work through hook. See [this](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_better_journal/commit/c726266068e3a7ff56ff6947dd244070cbaf6741)

Comment: Tanks for answering. I edit my issue. 
I agree, it's a general hook witch is called on all pages, but I want to display it only in wiki pages. So I add a condition, and it works. But I still can't get the wiki title on the wiki pages...

Comment: You can try to get access (I hope it is possible) to variables from [action](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/1.4-stable/app/controllers/wiki_controller.rb#L58) (for example `show`): `@page`, `@content`. You can check if they are available in the hook. And try to get title from them.

Comment: I've already tried @page.title (I can't make it work) but thanks =) I made a button with a onClick Javascript function, and I get the title with the page URL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!
It's not a very good way ... but it works ...

```
@url = context[:request].env["REDIRECT_URL"]
@url = @url.to_s.split('/')
@length = @url.length - 1
@title = @url[@length]
```